# Format date time in gwt with timezone

Tags: gwt, timezone

I am need to format a date and display it to users based on users location.

I am trying to format the time using the following code

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat("h:mm a z").format(new Date(timeInMillis))
```

This is the result i am getting "5:18 PM UTC-4" for new york users and "2:18 PM UTC-7" for seattle users. How do i generate string like "5:18 PM EST" for new york users and "2:18 PM PDT" for seattle users?

Note: the problem with using format(new Date(time), timezone) is that how to create a timezone object based on user locale? Timezone.createTimeZone(int) gives SimpleTimeZone implementation which will produce "UTC-4", in-order to generate "PDT", timezone has to be created with Timezone.createTimeZone(timezoneJson: string) but issue in this is that we have to pick the timezone at the compile time to create the input timezone json string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a [TimeZone object](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZone.html) to the formatter:

```
format.format(new Date(), timeZone));
```

Note that the best way to create TimeZone is from a JSON string that contains information on changes to time zone in the past. If you app does not deal with time in the past, then this may not be necessary.

Comment: Do keep in mind that GWT has all of the up-to-date timezone data built-in - you can `GWT.create` an instance of `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.constants.TimeZoneConstants` and get them all by name, or just pick out the specific ones you want. Warning - including all possible timezones will dramatically bloat your app, which is why Java's own TimeZone isn't emulated in core GWT.

Comment: but the question is how do you create timeZone object for users in various time zones?

Comment: Ask them which time zone they want and create time zone objects accordingly. Usually it is done in the settings or preferences for your app. You can also set a default time zone - where most of your users reside, so that those users don't have to change their settings. Finally, you can simply display time in your default time zone, make sure that you tell which time zone it is, and let users figure it out on their own. This is what many websites do, like ESPN. They say the game starts at 8pm ET, and users know what time this means for their own time zone.

Comment: Browser already knows the users zone, and get handles it up to certain extend thats why i see "5:18 PM UTC-4" or "2:18 PM UTC-7" based on location but what i want is "5:18 PM EST" see the difference, i don't want "UTC-4",  i want "EST" or "PDT" or what ever is relevant

Comment: Use one of predefined formats instead of `.getFormat("h:mm a z")`.